# How to Set Transfer encoding in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm using `Alamofire 5.0.0` in my iOS project, Now the problem is the default `Transfer-Encoding` of `Alamofire` is '`Chunked`' which is not supported by my server, Is there any way to set `Transfer-Encoding` to another value for example `identity` or `gzip`?

I'd be glad any help me.

Comment: `Alamofire.request(.POST, someURLString, parameters:["data":["verboseData":"veryVerbose"]], encoding:.JSON.gzipped)`

Comment: I don't find this  method in my Alamofire,may be it's version differentiations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `URLEncoding.httpBody` instead of `JSON.gzipped`

Comment: Unfortunately this not worked for me, after sending a request ,my server still receive the transfer-coding as Chunked.

Comment: Try this `JSONEncoding.default` it helps.

Comment: Opps, it's still not worked for me, my request is sending chunked request to my Apache server again.

Comment: Try this `Alamofire.request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: GZIPEncoding(), headers: mHeaders).response`                                                                                                                         , check this [https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/256]

Comment: It turns out my Xcode simulator caused this problem,anyway thanks ,bro.